# Crystal Reports xml path access denied

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, crystal-reports, access-denied

From about 5 hours I finish my project and when I test the application on another PC. It works and the installation package works correctly. But I had a problem that when I try to make a report using Crystal Report I got error

> Access to path file c:\programfiles......sample.xm  is denied

And that xml file is the report source, because the report rows coming from DataGridView that didn't take from a database it take value from ComboBoxes and TextBoxes. So I make that xml file to be as a source but on my PC it works

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XLSbx7H.png]

Comment: your application does not have the right permission to access your XML file.

Comment: i solve it but i got error when i want to make a report "The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception"